# iframe navigation using parameter

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

I have a page called 'mas.php' where i retrieve values from database. An IFrame is present in mas.php page. It is defined as follows:

```
<iframe width="523" height="234" scrolling="No" 
 width="500" height="145" src="mail-to.php" frameborder="0"
 name="myframe" ></iframe>
```

Now from mail-to.php page I have to navigate to mail.php for mailing.
The sequence is:

`(mas.php-->mail-to.php[iframe]--->mail.php)......`

here while using the iframe in 'mas.php' page can i navigate to 'mail-to.php' by defining id in iframe?

```
 <iframe width="523" height="234" scrolling="No" 
  width="500" height="145" src="mail-to.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"
  frameborder="0" name="myframe" ></iframe>
```

Comment: The best way to find out would be to try it yourself. Or do others have to check it for you?

Comment: @Michal,I have checked it..It did not work..